# Top and Left property not working! Why?

Tags: css, xhtml

I recently took up learning some css... and I am getting stuck on some very basic hurdles.

I can't get the top and left properties to work on this basic page that I was creating.

Below is all the code for that page... all the properties work except the top and left.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #firstdiv {border: 2px solid red;
                    position: absolute;
                    top:15px; 
                    left:25px:}
                #seconddiv {border: 2px solid green;
                    position: absolute;
                    top:65px; 
                    left:5px:}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="firstdiv">This is my first div </div>
<div id="seconddiv">This is my second div</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated!  = D

Comment: Well, for one thing you have `:` instead of `;` at the end of your two `left:` declarations.

Comment: Joe.  What can I say... I am blind.  Thank you so much!  = ) I will fix the issue.

Comment: If you are making a web page, and not actually using xml the html5 doctype is more appropriate as there's no reason to use xhtml and you probably wont be rendering the page as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have colons after left instead of semi-colons

```
#firstdiv {
    border: 2px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    top:15px; 
    left:25px;
} 
#seconddiv {
    border: 2px solid green; 
    position: absolute; 
    top:65px; 
    left:5px;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PckBd/ looks like that's the fix. That and if the '--' dashes are actually in the code, get rid of them too.

Comment: <html>
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
  #firstdiv {border: 2px solid red;
     position: absolute;
     top:15px; 
     left:25px;}
    #seconddiv {border: 2px solid green;
     position: absolute;
     top:65px; 
     left:5px;}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="firstdiv">This is my first div </div>
<div id="seconddiv">This is my second div</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: sorry, forgot to include the doctype at the top.  

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">